# Applescript works in Script Editor but not in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I am developing a mac application, which takes the username and password of user account and switches to that user account.

I have AppleScript which performs this action. this is working fine when I run it from the script editor. But the same script is not working when I use it in the mac app.

**Apple script to switch to user named **test**:**

```
set theUser to "test"
set thePassword to "test@123"
set theUser to do shell script "/usr/bin/id -u " & theUser
do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/'Menu Extras'/user.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID " & theUser
repeat 2 times
    delay 2
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "SecurityAgent"
                set value of text field 1 of window "Login" to thePassword
                key code 36
            end tell
        end tell
        exit repeat
    on error
        delay 1
    end try
end repeat
```

**objective-C code used in the Mac Application:**

```
NSAppleScript *switchUser = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
    @"set theUser to \"test\" \n"
    @"set thePassword to \"test@123\" \n"
    @"set theUser to do shell script \"/usr/bin/id -u \" & theUser \n"
    @"do shell script \"/System/Library/CoreServices/'Menu Extras'/user.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID \" & theUser \n"
    @"repeat 2 times \n"
    @"   delay 1 \n"
    @"   try \n"
    @"       tell application \"System Events\" \n"
    @"           tell process \"SecurityAgent\" \n"
    @"               set value of text field 1 of window \"Login\" to thePassword \n"
    @"               key code 36 \n"
    @"            end tell \n"
    @"       end tell \n"
    @"        exit repeat \n"
    @"    on error \n"
    @"        delay 1 \n"
    @"    end try \n"
    @"end repeat" ];
NSDictionary *err = nil;
[switchUser executeAndReturnError:&err];
if(err) {
        NSLog(@"***** Apple script returned error: %@", err);
    }
```

Please let me know if I am missing something while writing the code in objective C. Or if there is any other way to switch between users.

Comment: At least don’t ignore the possible error. Pass an `NSDictionary` pointer and have a look  what it contains. Is the app sandboxed? If yes you cannot run scripts with `NSAppleScript`

Comment: The app is not sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. the script is working fine, but when we are trying to switch the user all applications of the current user get killed. that is why it was not working.

In order to make this work, I had to run this script in the daemon service which will be running irrespective of user accounts.